# Excel: Insert a value of a cell into a parapraph

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to write a big paragraph and send to different people I want to replace the name with a value of a cell so I change them how I want.

Is there any possibility for this in excel or word? Google drive would be ok too.

Tried using SUBSTITUTE() and REPLACE() but they are very inconvience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ampersand operator to concatenate text and cell values, like this:

`="Hello " & B7 & ", my name is " & C7 & " and I would like to talk to you about"`

However, this kind of stuff is what Word Mail Merge was designed to do. Start a Mail Merge in Word, connect to the Excel file, then write your text with the merge fields to splice in the Excel data.

Mail merge can be used to create documents, as well as emails.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I will give this a try